# Error during registration of the .tlb file in a C# DLL for COM INTEROP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, com-interop

I have a DLL which I am trying to design with COM interop in order to use inside a VB6 program. When I try to build the solution, the following error shows up:

> The assembly *DLLFilePath* could
>   not be converted to a type library.
>   Type library exporter encountered an
>   error while processing '*DLLName.DLLName*, *DLLName*'. Error:
>   **Element not found.**

Then, I tried to manually register the `.tlb` using [RegAsm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), however I found a very similar error (error: `RA0000`).

I don't know the reason for this mistakes? Could it be because I am using the DataTable type, and it could not be compatible?

Comment: I remember trying to make a DataTable derived class com visible. Didn't work for me... not all the types exposed by the DataTable via properties/methods are com visible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have already found the solution for the problem! I was using the same GUID in the solution assembly and in the class declaration. By generating a new GUID, the problem was solved!

Comment: Fixed it for me too!  (the MS help for the error code that I was seeing referred to a ~10 yr old VB.NET issue - not helpful)